# Spring Angularjs - DELETE METHOD

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, h2

I have a problem with delete method. I try to delete a entity by Request Body.

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/remove", method = DELETE)
 public void remove(Package pack) {  
   packageRepository.delete(pack);   
}
```

And AngularJS:

```
    $http({
        method : 'DELETE',
        url : '/api/package/remove',
        data : pack

    }).then
```

Where pack is a Entity. What should i do ? All time i am getting message: Required request body is missing: public javax.xml.ws.Response com.controller.PackageController.remove(com.model.Package)

Class Package:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "Package")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Package {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

private String description;

private Double weight;

private Double xDimension;

private Double yDimension;

private Double zDimension;

private Double capacity;

private LocalDateTime whenTake;

private String timeString;


@OneToOne
private User user;

@OneToOne
private Warehouse warehouse;

@ManyToOne
@Null
@JsonIgnore
private Route route;
}
```

Json body:

```
 capacity: 20
 description: "Kolo jest okrągłe"
 id: 1
 name: "Koła Audi"
 timeString: "2017-11-24 18:43:23"
 user: {…}
   address: "Graniczna 25"
   email: null
   firmName: "Swinouscie Comapny"
   firstName: "Karol"
   id: 1
   lastName: "Cichowski"
   telephoneNumber: "700880774"
 warehouse: {…}
   address: "Sportowa 16"
   id: 1
   name: "Magazyn Amazon"
   telephoneNumber: "74-816-342-465"
weight: 29
whenTake: null
xDimension: null
yDimension: null
zDimension: null
```

Comment: Can it be that the body is just ignored? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request

Comment: Please post the relevant code of `Package` class and `pack` in angularjs

Comment: maybe but what other i should send? only id ? I try with @PathVariable and still this same error

Comment: by using F12 in Firefox i see a pack's Json body and is correct. 
I try with headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but its dosnt work

Comment: I think it's more common to just pass the `id` on a `DELETE`, which could be added as querystring parameter.

Comment: if you don't post the json sent by angularjs it will be difficult for us to help you. `headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` won't help either

Comment: It is possible that can be a problem with h2? i can create any object but what i want to delete it ?

Answer (score 1):

annotate your pack as the request body :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove", method = DELETE)
  public void remove(@RequestBody Package pack) {  
  packageRepository.delete(pack);   
   }
```

Comment: instead of `void` put `Package`as your return type, and inside your method after deleting the pack `return pack;`

Comment: i got 200 -> by F12 i see a body paramteres which i send and output (answer) -> all package paramteres are nulls. But when i refresh page and when i try to get all exist elements still i see this same element whose i deleted ;/                                                                              I see table in h2 and this element is still there.

Comment: @MikeEvans then you're hitting the controller but now your problem is with persistence?

Comment: With persistence? Can you explain?